launch json can't find the path of file
I followed this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_run-helloworldcpp link's instructions for compiling cpp file but it didn't work as expected...
in that link it didn't mention to any step that requires setting gcc path so that compiler can check for libraries in compile time
I don't think this is even relevant...my question is launch.json file is created by default?and if it's not how should I configure it?
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations":[
      {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
  

I already tried adding path of file to program section but it didn't help.
